# Coding Wordpress Issues

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Well if you check out the theme I'm making with my own knowledge, ([DaniThemes](http://demilovatoonline.com/danithemes)) the entries are way too far from each other. That's because of this part of the css:

```
margin-top:1050px;
```

I don't want the posts to be on the top, I want them to be away from the top because there's where the header is. Using 'margin-top', the posts are away from the top BUT they are away from each other too...

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following css should fix that problem:

```
.post:first-child {
margin-top: 1100px;
}
```

and remove `margin-top: 1100px;` from .post

The above should only add the 1100px to the first post and not the rest.